# Storing value into a list

Tags: python, list

```
factor= []
number= int(input("what is the number?"))
for i in range (1,number):
    remainder= number%i
    if remainder== 0:
       i= factor[i]
       print (factor[i])
```

it says list is out of range, I am trying to store i into the list

Comment: change `i= factor[i]` to `factor.append(i)` then in a beginning of a new line `print(factor)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should look up the basics of lists in python. You're setting i to the value at factor[i] (which is an empty array). Do what Jamiu said above, but you have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You should see it in any tutorial - you have to use `.append()` to add element at the end of list.

Your list `factor` is empty and you can't get element using index `factor[i]` and you can put element in place `factor[i]` because it doesn't exist.

```
factor = []

#number = int(input("what is the number?"))
number = 12

for i in range(1, number+1):
    
    remainder = number % i
    
    if remainder == 0:
        factor.append(i)
        #print(factor)

# --- after loop ---

print(factor)
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]
```

---

And if you want to use `index` to put elements on list then first you should create list correct size (with some values - ie. `0`)

```
factor = [0] * number
```

and later put data in selected places

```
factor[i] = i
```

but in your code this would give many `0` and it is not useful.

```
#number = int(input("what is the number?"))
number = 12

factor = [0] * (number+1)

for i in range(1, number+1):
    
    remainder = number % i
    
    if remainder == 0:
        factor[i] = i
        #print(factor)
       
# --- after loop ---

print(factor)
```

Result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
number=[int(input("what is the number? "))]
print(type(number))
print(number)
```

will result in

```
what is the number? 5
<class 'list'>
[5]
```